# Using new MS C++ compiler with old Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide, compiler-construction, visual-c++-6

I want to use a recent MS C++ compiler (I need TR1) with old IDE (Visual C 6.0). I heard that I can download free command line MS C++ compiler only. Is it possible? Can I use new compiler with old IDE? If so what additional problems may arise?

I want to keep VS6 cause I'm familiar with it. I want to use MS implementation of TR1 cause I expect it to be faster than Boost.

Comment: Explaining why you want to do this will help answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually download a free version of the **new IDE**, the [Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vc/). It has a few limitations compared to the non-free versions (e.g. no plugin support) but for most applications it's still vastly superior to VS6.

Comment: +1, bite the bullet now and learn the new VS, MS put alot of effort in to making it easier for both VB and C++ developers to upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio versions will install side by side quite happily.

Just avoid double clicking on solution files (this will open the latest), instead open from the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Boost.TR1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_tr1.html)?

Comment: I thought that MS implementation is faster. Is it really so?

Comment: I don't know of any performance benchmarks, but Boost.TR1 can be configured to use the native TR1 if it is available (by defining BOOST_HAS_TR1, I believe). That way you can use the boost implementation until you are able to switch to a version of VC++ which has TR1 without much effort.